# Select esconder/mostrar DIVs de acordo com o valor selecionado (jquery)

Tags: jquery, option

Tenho um select e alguns divs assim:

```
<select name="numerounidades" id="numerounidades">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
```

Aí precisava de uma função em jquery que esconde ou mostra os divs de acordo com a seleção, ex:

```
Valor 1: só mostra o div id 1
Valor 2: mostra o div id 1 e 2
Valor 3: mostra o div id 1, 2 e 3
Valor 4: mostra o div id 1, 2, 3 e 4
```

Tem uma forma de montar uma função jQuery simples pra isso? A única forma que sei é fazer um if para cada valor selecionado.

**EDITADO**
Montei uma gambiarra que deu certo, mas acredito que exista uma forma melhor de se fazer isso certo?

```
<div id="1" class="d1 d2 d3 d4">1</div>
<div id="2" class="d2 d3 d4">2</div>
<div id="3" class="d3 d4">3</div>
<div id="4" class="d4">4</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.d1').hide();
$('.d2').hide();
$('.d3').hide();
$('.d4').hide();
    $("#numerounidades").change(function(){
$('.d1').hide();
$('.d2').hide();
$('.d3').hide();
$('.d4').hide();
        var numero = 'd'+$(this).val();
        $('.'+numero).show();
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando um loop `for()` fica facil:

```js
$("#1,#2,#3,#4").hide();
$("#numerounidades").change(function(){
    var num = parseInt($('#numerounidades option:selected').val());
    for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        $("#"+i).show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="numerounidades" id="numerounidades">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<div id="1">a</div>
<div id="2">b</div>
<div id="3">c</div>
<div id="4">d</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito, Brigadão!

Comment: Eu quem agradeço por poder ajudar

Comment: na verdade tem uma alteração pra fazer, se seleciona 2 e depois 3, vai normal, mas se selecionar 1 de volta, ele não ta escondendo os outros

Comment: minha gambiarra é colocar $("#1,#2,#3,#4").hide(); no inicio do .change

Comment: isso, vc executa o fechamento dps a abertura

Answer (score -1):

Caso queira uma solução com javascript puro

```js
var numero_unidades = document.getElementById('numerounidades');

numero_unidades.onchange = () => {
  
  var optionSelected = numero_unidades.options[numero_unidades.selectedIndex].value;

  hide(['1', '2', '3', '4']);

  if(optionSelected){
    for(var index = 1; index <= optionSelected; index++)
      show(`${[index]}`);
  } 

}

function hide(array) {
    for (var item = 0; item < array.length; item++)
        document.getElementById(array[item]).style.display = 'none';
}

function show(array) {
    for (var item = 0; item < array.length; item++)
        document.getElementById(array[item]).style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<select name="numerounidades" id="numerounidades">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<div id="1" >a</div>
<div id="2" style="display: none">b</div>
<div id="3" style="display: none">c</div>
<div id="4" style="display: none">d</div>
```